# Difficulty with testing for ranges of integer values

Tags: c++

I am writing filter program grouping kindergarten, preschool and school for ages I wrote if program but it outputs conditions wrong who is willing to take look at my program?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int  input;// age
    int kindergarden , preschool , school;
    cin >> input;

    if (2 <= 4)
    {
        cout << "kindergarden" << "\n\n";

    if (5 <= 6)
    {
        cout << "preschool" << "\n\n";
    }

    else (7 <= 15);
    {
        cout << "school" << "\n\n";
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Paul R what's with that edit back to broken markdown?

Comment: @EKW I was reverting someone's “fix” for the incorrect code formatting but went too far - should be OK now.

Comment: @Gunay if you had enabled compiler warnings then the compiler would have helped you with one of your bugs.

Answer (score 4):

Your first if statement is `if (2 <= 4)`. This will always be true. 2 is always less than 4. Inside that if statement, is another if statement, asking if `5 <= 6`. This will always be true also. Thus, it will output "kindergarten preschool".

I assume you want to check if input is within the two values in your if statements. To do so, you would write

```
if(2 <= input && input <= 4)
```

Also, you should bring the second if statement outside of the first. To do that, you should put your `}` before the second if statement, not after the last one.

Edit: As YSC pointed out, there's another issue: `else (7 <= 15);`. There are two issues with this:

1) It should be `else if(condition)`, as plain `else` statements do not expect a condition.

2) It should not end with `;`. It should end with `{` to hold the code that should be executed if the condition is true.

Comment: You might also want to point out how the incorrect code formatting makes the second bug you mention hard to spot.

Comment: What about `else (7 <= 15)`?

Comment: @YSC Yikes! totally missed that one!

Answer (score 1):

Your first if is wrapped around two others. Because you 're used flat indentation of source code, it's very hard to spot.

```
if (2 <= input && input  <= 4)
{
    cout << "kindergarden" << "\n\n";
} // here was your mistake

else if (5 <= input && input  <= 6)
{
    cout << "preschool" << "\n\n";
}

else if (7 <= input && input  <= 15) // ; another mistake
{
    cout << "school" << "\n\n";
}
```

You can make it into one loop actually, in a dozen various ways

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    int  input = 0;// age
    const struct Cat 
    {
        int age;
        string category;
    } classes[] = {  {2, "kindergarden"}, {5, "preschool"}, {7, "school"}, {16, ""} };

    cin >> input;

    // without range loop this looks tricky
    for(const Cat *c = std::end(classes)-1; c >= std::begin(classes); c-- )
        if ( input >= c->age ) 
        {
            std::cout << c-> category;
            break;
        }
}
```

The only advantage would be aggregation of conditions in one place. Of course, there can be more parameters for condition, e.g. upper and lower bracket instead of lower only.